# mod_rewrite: access URL-path in RewriteCond

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How can I match against the URL-path from the `RewriteCond` in a `.htaccess`?

I'd like this because I'm trying make one subdirectory of my web server transparently proxy + cache requests to another server, and I'd like to write the `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:CACHE_BASE}/%{URL_PATH}" -f
RewriteRule (.*) "%{ENV:CACHE_BASE}/$1" [L]
RewriteRule (.*) "download_and_cache.cgi?$1"
```

So that requests for files which already exist in the cache will be sent from within Apache, and requests for files which aren't in the cache will be handled by the `download_and_cache.cgi` script (which will put them in the cache).

NB: I can't use `%(REQUEST_URI}`, because if the `.htaccess` lives at `/foo/`, a request for `/foo/README.txt` will result in a cache check for `$CACHE_BASE/foo/README.txt`, instead of `$CACHE_BASE/README.txt` as it should.

Answer (score 2):

My Mod_rewrite is a little rusty but shouldn't you be able to use the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive to account for "/foo"

Or I think you could use a back reference something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foo/(.*)
RewriteCond "%{ENV:CACHE_BASE}/%1" -f
```

Or if I'm following it all correctly
Rewrite first to the cache, then check to see if you need to download it first.
Like so:

```
RewriteRule foo/(.*) "%{ENV:CACHE_BASE}/$1" [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule (.*) "download_and_cache.cgi?$1"
```

If you can using [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) would make the above a little cleaner.